# Custom Android Keyboard Input Filtering

Tags: android, keyboard, filter

I have an `EditText` that is to collect input for a basic calculator. I want to bring up the numeric keyboard, and thus I set `android:inputType` to `numberDecimal|numberSigned`. Problem is, the `EditText filters` out all characters that aren't numeric, such as `"(", ")", "/", "*"`.

I have tried overriding this behavior by setting a custom Inp`u`tFilter which filters nothing out, but it seems to have no affect on the `EditText`.

Is there any way for me to display the numeric `soft keyboard` without the filtering behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but I believe setting the inputType to the phone one will allow those characters through.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I tried by creating an EditText and setting "android:inputType" to "phone". Typing letter on the keyboard just outputs numbers. Anything I missed?